# Grafana alert notification policy mute is not working

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I have configured mute notification policy with my Grafana alert but the alert is still triggering under muted timeframe.

My notification policy looks like this:
[Current notification mute setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txuDl.png)